# Iterate over folder and rename all files with suffix added

Tags: windows-10, shell, batch

I have 100 of files in a folder Drive C:\Users\Drive. I would like to rename each of the file with suffix "D_" to the beginning of file name.

```
Ex: Original File name : file1.txt
    After suffix name : D_file1.txt
```

I am using batch script command to rename them with

```
for %%a in (Users\Drive\*) do REN  D_%%a.

But output is showing as D_Users\Drive\file1.txt. Not sure how to fix this.
```

Comment: `for %%a in (Users\Drive\*) do REN "%%~dpnxa" "D_%%~dpnxa"`

Comment: I dont think above command is working for me. D_ is added to complete file path and not just to the file.

Comment: You need to write a script to rename the folders and the files separately, As we do not offer a free script writing service, you will have to do this yourself. Feel free to try it and post a question about it if it does not do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your 2 cents ..

Comment: `for %%a in (Users\Drive\*) do REN "%%~dpnxa" "%%~dpD_nxa"` should work

Comment: This didnt work either. The D_is added to the start of the file path..